# How do I use same view model but for different view excluding the required properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have a view model for a view AddAppointment. It has many properties of which 2 are **Required** (I wrote Required attribute over it).

Now I want to use the same model for another view but excluding the properties which are required but it doesn't work i.e. it's invalid.

What to do apart from writing another view model?

View Model:

```
  public class AddBookingsViewModel
    {


        public string CustomerName { get; set; }


        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        public string VehicleRegNo { get; set; }
        public short fk_VehicleMakeID { get; set; }
        public string VehicleModel { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select appointment time ")]
        public int fk_TimeSlotID { get; set; }

        public byte fk_BookingModeID { get; set; }
        public int EntryUserID { get; set; }
        public int ReturnBookingID { get; set; }    

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Fill in the appointment date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }

    }
```

View: (Where it is used)

```
@model ZahidCarWash.ViewModels.AddBookingsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Appointment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<!--  page banner -->

<!--  end page banner  -->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!--  appointments -->
    <div id="appointments" class="appointment-main-block appointment-two-main-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section text-center">
                    <h3 class="section-heading text-center">Get an Appointment</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="appointment-block">

                        <h5 class="form-heading-title"><span class="form-heading-no">1.</span>Vehicle Information</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="dropdown">

                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.fk_VehicleMakeID, new SelectList(ZahidCarWash.DAL.VehicleMakesRepository.getVehicleMakes(), "VehicleMakeID", "MakeTitle"),
          new { @class = "form-control" })

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.VehicleModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Vehicle Model" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.VehicleRegNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Vehicle Reg No." } })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h5 class="form-heading-title"><span class="form-heading-no">2.</span>Contact Details</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Customer Name" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "ErrorMessages" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.ContactNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Contact Number." } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ContactNo, "", new { @class = "ErrorMessages" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Book Now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
  public JsonResult AddManualAppointment(AddBookingsViewModel AddBookingVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AddBookingVM.fk_BookingModeID = 2;
            int ReturnRowsCount = BookingRep.InsertCustomerAppointments(AddBookingVM, out ReturnStatus, out ReturnMessage, out ReturnBookingID);

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return Json(new { ReturnMessageJSON = ReturnMessage, ReturnStatusJSON = ReturnStatus });
    }
```

Data is passed through ajax:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">



        //to add an appointment

        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                return;
            }

            var url = '@Url.Action("AddManualAppointment")';
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.post(url, data, function (response) {

                if (response.ReturnStatusJSON == true) {

                    swal("Booked !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "success");


                    $("#VehicleRegNo").val("");
                    $("#VehicleModel").val("");

                    $("#CustomerName").val("");
                    $("#ContactNo").val("");


                }
                else {
                    swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
    <!--End Custom Scripts-->
}
```

Comment: You cant (unless you use a conditional `[RequiredIf]` validation attribute based on another property in your model). But you can always create a BaseViewModel with the common properties, and then the concrete view models inherit from that adding the 2 other properties (with  `[Required]`  attributes on one, but not the other)

Comment: what is Bind(Include) used for?

Comment: Its not appropriate when you have view models (you are already protected against over-posting attacks) - But it specifies which properties to include/exclude from binding - so its not appropriate in your case (you do not want to exclude the properties)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the quick and dirty way is to use @Html.Hiddenfor and fill the value with a new datetime from inside your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can split your view model into a version with and without the required attributes using inheritance:

```
public class AddBookingsViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string VehicleRegNo { get; set; }
    public short fk_VehicleMakeID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleModel { get; set; }
    public byte fk_BookingModeID { get; set; }
    public int EntryUserID { get; set; }
    public int ReturnBookingID { get; set; }    
}

public class AddBookingsViewModelWithAppointment : AddBookingsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select appointment time ")]
    public int fk_TimeSlotID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Fill in the appointment date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to use the appropriate view model in your situation and still maintain compatibilty through polymorphism.

If you need the optional properties in your base class, you can make your properties virtual and apply the attribute in the derived class:

```
public class AddBookingsViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string VehicleRegNo { get; set; }
    public short fk_VehicleMakeID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleModel { get; set; }
    public byte fk_BookingModeID { get; set; }
    public int EntryUserID { get; set; }
    public int ReturnBookingID { get; set; }    
    public virtual int fk_TimeSlotID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }
}

public class AddBookingsViewModelWithAppointment : AddBookingsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select appointment time ")]
    public override int fk_TimeSlotID {
        get => base.fk_TimeSlotID;
        set => base.fk_TimeSlotID = value;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Fill in the appointment date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public override DateTime? AppointmentDate {
        get => base.AppointmentDate;
        set => base.AppointmentDate = value;
    }
}
```

Use the veriant that works best in your business case.